# Weird redirection when updating datas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updates, scaffolding

I generated a scaffold for a portfolio via the Rails command, `rails g portfolio titre:string, thumbnail:string lien:string description:text`. I also added FriendlyId to get a better URL, and that's about all. Here is the 'update' action.

```
  def update
    if @portfolio.update(portfolio_params)
      redirect_to @portfolio, notice: 'Portfolio mis à jour.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

However, when trying to update a project in my portfolio, the submit button tries to get to 'portfolio#update' via patch, but puts a '.' instead of a '/' which gives me `No route matches [PATCH] "/portfolios.test-1"`

For the route, I only have `resources :portfolios`

**edit : added the form**

```
<%= form_for @portfolio, url: portfolios_path(@portfolio) do |f| %>
  <% if portfolio.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(portfolio.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this portfolio from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% portfolio.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :titre %>
    <%= f.text_field :titre %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :categorie %>
    <%= f.text_field :categorie %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :thumbnail %>
    <%= f.file_field :thumbnail %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lien %>
    <%= f.text_field :lien %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Enregistrer' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I didn't have any other possibilities that doing `@portfolio, url: portfolios_path(@portfolio)`, otherwise Rails considered that '@portfolio' was nil

**edit 2 : added the private 'set_portfolio' params**

```
private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_portfolio
    @portfolio = Portfolio.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
```

What's wrong with my app ?

Comment: Can we see the code for the form?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`portfolios_path` is the collection path.

<strike>change it `portfolio_path` should fix it.</strike>

`<%= form_for @portfolio, url: portfolio_path(@portfolio) do |f| %>`

I guess you are going to use this form for creating new portfolio as well, so change it to `<%= form_for(@portfolio) %>` should fix it and will also work for both cases. `form_for` will submit to correct path.

Comment: Well now I'm getting `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"portfolios", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`, while targetting the line where I put `form_for`. I believe Rails doesn't get that this is the 'new' action instead of the 'show'

Comment: What bothers me is that I tried a lot of things, and I remember trying this, even though it failed. Well now it works, so thank you !